# Aligning navigation area

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make a simple navigation area but I'm having a small issue getting everything to sit correctly. What I'm trying to do is make each tab slot up next to each other but for some reason underneath each one there is a space. Can anyone see where I'm going wrong here?

Also this has caused my image area and the text area to no longer be inline with each other, so I also can't seem to work out why that has happened as well.

```js
function menu1() {
  document.getElementById("menu1").className = "menuOn";
  document.getElementById("menu2").className = "menuOff";
  document.getElementById("menu3").className = "menuOff";
  document.getElementById("menu4").className = "menuOff";
  document.getElementById("menu5").className = "menuOff";
  document.getElementById("menu6").className = "menuOff";
}

function menu2() {
  document.getElementById("menu1").className = "menuOff";
  document.getElementById("menu2").className = "menuOn";
  document.getElementById("menu3").className = "menuOff";
  document.getElementById("menu4").className = "menuOff";
  document.getElementById("menu5").className = "menuOff";
  document.getElementById("menu6").className = "menuOff";
}

function menu3() {
  document.getElementById("menu1").className = "menuOff";
  document.getElementById("menu2").className = "menuOff";
  document.getElementById("menu3").className = "menuOn";
  document.getElementById("menu4").className = "menuOff";
  document.getElementById("menu5").className = "menuOff";
  document.getElementById("menu6").className = "menuOff";
}

function menu4() {
  document.getElementById("menu1").className = "menuOff";
  document.getElementById("menu2").className = "menuOff";
  document.getElementById("menu3").className = "menuOff";
  document.getElementById("menu4").className = "menuOn";
  document.getElementById("menu5").className = "menuOff";
  document.getElementById("menu6").className = "menuOff";
}

function menu5() {
  document.getElementById("menu1").className = "menuOff";
  document.getElementById("menu2").className = "menuOff";
  document.getElementById("menu3").className = "menuOff";
  document.getElementById("menu4").className = "menuOff";
  document.getElementById("menu5").className = "menuOn";
  document.getElementById("menu6").className = "menuOff";
}

function menu6() {
  document.getElementById("menu1").className = "menuOff";
  document.getElementById("menu2").className = "menuOff";
  document.getElementById("menu3").className = "menuOff";
  document.getElementById("menu4").className = "menuOff";
  document.getElementById("menu5").className = "menuOff";
  document.getElementById("menu6").className = "menuOn";
}
```

```css
.menuOn {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #2f8fcb;
}

.menuOff {
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: #e5eff6;
  color: #666;
}

#menuTab {
  width: 25%;
  font-size: 13px;
}

#listPic {
  float: left;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border: 2px solid #000;
  margin-top: 13px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-right: 5px;
}

#listName {
  padding-top: 5px;
}

#listName p {
  margin: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div id="menuTab">
  <div id="menu1" class="menuOn" onclick="menu1()">
    <div id="listPic">
    </div>
    <div id="listName">
      <p>Health & Safety</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="menu2" class="menuOff" onclick="menu2()">
    <div id="listPic">
    </div>
    <div id="listName">
      <p>Enviromental</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="menu3" class="menuOff" onclick="menu3()">
    <div id="listPic">
    </div>
    <div id="listName">
      <p>Accounting</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="menu4" class="menuOff" onclick="menu4()">
    <div id="listPic">
    </div>
    <div id="listName">
      <p>Haulage</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="menu5" class="menuOff" onclick="menu5()">
    <div id="listPic">
    </div>
    <div id="listName">
      <p>Emails</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="menu6" class="menuOff" onclick="menu6()">
    <div id="listPic">
    </div>
    <div id="listName">
      <p>Announcements</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you float the content of your div, it shrinks as if the content wasn't there. Add `overflow:auto;` to `.menuOn` and `.menuOff` to have it extend over the div's contents.

```js
function menu1() {
  document.getElementById("menu1").className = "menuOn";
  document.getElementById("menu2").className = "menuOff";
  document.getElementById("menu3").className = "menuOff";
  document.getElementById("menu4").className = "menuOff";
  document.getElementById("menu5").className = "menuOff";
  document.getElementById("menu6").className = "menuOff";
}

function menu2() {
  document.getElementById("menu1").className = "menuOff";
  document.getElementById("menu2").className = "menuOn";
  document.getElementById("menu3").className = "menuOff";
  document.getElementById("menu4").className = "menuOff";
  document.getElementById("menu5").className = "menuOff";
  document.getElementById("menu6").className = "menuOff";
}

function menu3() {
  document.getElementById("menu1").className = "menuOff";
  document.getElementById("menu2").className = "menuOff";
  document.getElementById("menu3").className = "menuOn";
  document.getElementById("menu4").className = "menuOff";
  document.getElementById("menu5").className = "menuOff";
  document.getElementById("menu6").className = "menuOff";
}

function menu4() {
  document.getElementById("menu1").className = "menuOff";
  document.getElementById("menu2").className = "menuOff";
  document.getElementById("menu3").className = "menuOff";
  document.getElementById("menu4").className = "menuOn";
  document.getElementById("menu5").className = "menuOff";
  document.getElementById("menu6").className = "menuOff";
}

function menu5() {
  document.getElementById("menu1").className = "menuOff";
  document.getElementById("menu2").className = "menuOff";
  document.getElementById("menu3").className = "menuOff";
  document.getElementById("menu4").className = "menuOff";
  document.getElementById("menu5").className = "menuOn";
  document.getElementById("menu6").className = "menuOff";
}

function menu6() {
  document.getElementById("menu1").className = "menuOff";
  document.getElementById("menu2").className = "menuOff";
  document.getElementById("menu3").className = "menuOff";
  document.getElementById("menu4").className = "menuOff";
  document.getElementById("menu5").className = "menuOff";
  document.getElementById("menu6").className = "menuOn";
}
```

```css
.menuOn {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #2f8fcb;
  overflow:auto;
}

.menuOff {
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: #e5eff6;
  color: #666;  overflow:auto;

}

#menuTab {
  width: 25%;
  font-size: 13px;
}

#listPic {
  float: left;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border: 2px solid #000;
  margin-top: 13px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-right: 5px;
}

#listName {
  padding-top: 5px;
}

#listName p {
  margin: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div id="menuTab">
  <div id="menu1" class="menuOn" onclick="menu1()">
    <div id="listPic">
    </div>
    <div id="listName">
      <p>Health & Safety</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="menu2" class="menuOff" onclick="menu2()">
    <div id="listPic">
    </div>
    <div id="listName">
      <p>Enviromental</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="menu3" class="menuOff" onclick="menu3()">
    <div id="listPic">
    </div>
    <div id="listName">
      <p>Accounting</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="menu4" class="menuOff" onclick="menu4()">
    <div id="listPic">
    </div>
    <div id="listName">
      <p>Haulage</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="menu5" class="menuOff" onclick="menu5()">
    <div id="listPic">
    </div>
    <div id="listName">
      <p>Emails</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="menu6" class="menuOff" onclick="menu6()">
    <div id="listPic">
    </div>
    <div id="listName">
      <p>Announcements</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't clear your floats. You need to clear float after `menuOn` and `menuOff`.

```
.menuOn {
    overflow: hidden;
    clear: both;
}
.menuOff {
    overflow: hidden;
    clear: both;
}
```

Comment: You need to explain, correct and update the code. This isn;t an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I have just changed the floats to be `inline-block` and added `vertical-align:middle`. The floats were messing up the flow of the elements.

```js
function menu1() {
  document.getElementById("menu1").className = "menuOn";
  document.getElementById("menu2").className = "menuOff";
  document.getElementById("menu3").className = "menuOff";
  document.getElementById("menu4").className = "menuOff";
  document.getElementById("menu5").className = "menuOff";
  document.getElementById("menu6").className = "menuOff";
}

function menu2() {
  document.getElementById("menu1").className = "menuOff";
  document.getElementById("menu2").className = "menuOn";
  document.getElementById("menu3").className = "menuOff";
  document.getElementById("menu4").className = "menuOff";
  document.getElementById("menu5").className = "menuOff";
  document.getElementById("menu6").className = "menuOff";
}

function menu3() {
  document.getElementById("menu1").className = "menuOff";
  document.getElementById("menu2").className = "menuOff";
  document.getElementById("menu3").className = "menuOn";
  document.getElementById("menu4").className = "menuOff";
  document.getElementById("menu5").className = "menuOff";
  document.getElementById("menu6").className = "menuOff";
}

function menu4() {
  document.getElementById("menu1").className = "menuOff";
  document.getElementById("menu2").className = "menuOff";
  document.getElementById("menu3").className = "menuOff";
  document.getElementById("menu4").className = "menuOn";
  document.getElementById("menu5").className = "menuOff";
  document.getElementById("menu6").className = "menuOff";
}

function menu5() {
  document.getElementById("menu1").className = "menuOff";
  document.getElementById("menu2").className = "menuOff";
  document.getElementById("menu3").className = "menuOff";
  document.getElementById("menu4").className = "menuOff";
  document.getElementById("menu5").className = "menuOn";
  document.getElementById("menu6").className = "menuOff";
}

function menu6() {
  document.getElementById("menu1").className = "menuOff";
  document.getElementById("menu2").className = "menuOff";
  document.getElementById("menu3").className = "menuOff";
  document.getElementById("menu4").className = "menuOff";
  document.getElementById("menu5").className = "menuOff";
  document.getElementById("menu6").className = "menuOn";
}
```

```css
.menuOn {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #2f8fcb;
}

.menuOff {
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: #e5eff6;
  color: #666;
}

#menuTab {
  width: 25%;
  font-size: 13px;
  display: inline-block;
}
#listPic {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border: 2px solid #000;
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-right: 5px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

#listName {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

#listName p {
  margin-left: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div id="menuTab">
  <div id="menu1" class="menuOn" onclick="menu1()">
    <div id="listPic">
    </div>
    <div id="listName">
      <p>Health & Safety</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="menu2" class="menuOff" onclick="menu2()">
    <div id="listPic">
    </div>
    <div id="listName">
      <p>Enviromental</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="menu3" class="menuOff" onclick="menu3()">
    <div id="listPic">
    </div>
    <div id="listName">
      <p>Accounting</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="menu4" class="menuOff" onclick="menu4()">
    <div id="listPic">
    </div>
    <div id="listName">
      <p>Haulage</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="menu5" class="menuOff" onclick="menu5()">
    <div id="listPic">
    </div>
    <div id="listName">
      <p>Emails</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="menu6" class="menuOff" onclick="menu6()">
    <div id="listPic">
    </div>
    <div id="listName">
      <p>Announcements</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

For a start, you're using id where you should be using class, on `listPic` and on `listName`. Personally, I'd recommend using `display: inline-block;` to align divs, instead of using `float: left;`.

See snippet:

```js
function menu1() {
  document.getElementById("menu1").className = "menuOn";
  document.getElementById("menu2").className = "menuOff";
  document.getElementById("menu3").className = "menuOff";
  document.getElementById("menu4").className = "menuOff";
  document.getElementById("menu5").className = "menuOff";
  document.getElementById("menu6").className = "menuOff";
}

function menu2() {
  document.getElementById("menu1").className = "menuOff";
  document.getElementById("menu2").className = "menuOn";
  document.getElementById("menu3").className = "menuOff";
  document.getElementById("menu4").className = "menuOff";
  document.getElementById("menu5").className = "menuOff";
  document.getElementById("menu6").className = "menuOff";
}

function menu3() {
  document.getElementById("menu1").className = "menuOff";
  document.getElementById("menu2").className = "menuOff";
  document.getElementById("menu3").className = "menuOn";
  document.getElementById("menu4").className = "menuOff";
  document.getElementById("menu5").className = "menuOff";
  document.getElementById("menu6").className = "menuOff";
}

function menu4() {
  document.getElementById("menu1").className = "menuOff";
  document.getElementById("menu2").className = "menuOff";
  document.getElementById("menu3").className = "menuOff";
  document.getElementById("menu4").className = "menuOn";
  document.getElementById("menu5").className = "menuOff";
  document.getElementById("menu6").className = "menuOff";
}

function menu5() {
  document.getElementById("menu1").className = "menuOff";
  document.getElementById("menu2").className = "menuOff";
  document.getElementById("menu3").className = "menuOff";
  document.getElementById("menu4").className = "menuOff";
  document.getElementById("menu5").className = "menuOn";
  document.getElementById("menu6").className = "menuOff";
}

function menu6() {
  document.getElementById("menu1").className = "menuOff";
  document.getElementById("menu2").className = "menuOff";
  document.getElementById("menu3").className = "menuOff";
  document.getElementById("menu4").className = "menuOff";
  document.getElementById("menu5").className = "menuOff";
  document.getElementById("menu6").className = "menuOn";
}
```

```css
.menuOn {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #2f8fcb;
}

.menuOff {
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: #e5eff6;
  color: #666;
}

#menuTab {
  width: 25%;
  font-size: 13px;
}

.listPic {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border: 2px solid #000;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
}

.listName {
  display: inline-block;
}

.listName p {
  margin: 0;
  padding-top: 12px;
}
#menuTab > div {
  width: 155px;
  height: 34px;
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<div id="menuTab">
  <div id="menu1" class="menuOn" onclick="menu1()">
    <div class="listPic">
    </div>
    <div class="listName">
      <p>Health & Safety</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="menu2" class="menuOff" onclick="menu2()">
    <div class="listPic">
    </div>
    <div class="listName">
      <p>Enviromental</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="menu3" class="menuOff" onclick="menu3()">
    <div class="listPic">
    </div>
    <div class="listName">
      <p>Accounting</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="menu4" class="menuOff" onclick="menu4()">
    <div class="listPic">
    </div>
    <div class="listName">
      <p>Haulage</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="menu5" class="menuOff" onclick="menu5()">
    <div class="listPic">
    </div>
    <div class="listName">
      <p>Emails</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="menu6" class="menuOff" onclick="menu6()">
    <div class="listPic">
    </div>
    <div class="listName">
      <p>Announcements</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```